# Adverb for "syntax"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Instead of saying, "*they are the same in syntax*", how to say it the other way, e.g., "*they are *syntaxly* the same*"?

http://www.tfd.com/syntax has no entry of its adverb form either. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to say something rude about that dictionary, but apparently many of them fail to make the connection between *syntax* and *syntactic*.  Weird.

Comment: "Syntactic" is the adjective from "syntax", and "syntactically" is the adverb form.

Comment: There are a number of similar English words ending in **-axis**, Greek in origin, which entered English via medieval Latin. E.g.   praxis, parataxis, anaphylaxis, prophylaxis. Their adjectival forms all become -ctic-.  Practical, paratactic, anaphylactic, prophylactic.

Comment: @TRomano nice! Also (words ending in **-exis**) like lexis. Although lectic is not found at dictionaries (lexical is), eclectic and dialectic have the same original Greek root **-lex** .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's [syntactically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syntactically):

> according to the rules of syntax

Remember that the adverb-forming suffix *-ly* is usually attached to adjectives rather than nouns. The adjectives corresponding to *syntax* are *syntactic* and *syntactical*.

Whenever there's a pair of collateral adjectives ending in *-ic* and *-ical*, the corresponding adverb ending in *-ically* is preferred over the one with *-icly* even if the adjective ending in *-ic* is more common.

Comment: Apparently [syntaxical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/syntaxical) is also a word.  But not one *I* would use.

Comment: I can only imagine *syntaxical* being used in the expression *syntaxically delicious*, if that exists.

Comment: ...only if sprinkled with some *syntactic* sugar.

Comment: You may wish to consider 'grammatically', depending on the context you're using it in.